# How to mute squad member in Warzone 2.0 DMZ

Tags: call-of-duty-warzone-2.0

I'm playing in a party and a specific team mate is very loud in the channel.

Some people suggest that I can mute them in the Channels menu, but I can see no MUTE option at all in the corner.

I should see this:

[image]

I see this:

[image]

In the context menu there is no mute option:

[image]

So, how can I mute this player?

EDIT:
Everyone is okay with this? Noone is bothered by noisy players?

EDIT 2:
After a few updates, it is still unavailable. Even the other game type is missing this option. That is just...painful.

Comment: Right click the player? As I recall the UI has right click dropdown menus.

Comment: @Neon1024 There is no mute option in the context menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took them a whole season to fix that issue. In version 1.11, they finally implemented that missing feature :)

[image]